# inputAccessoryView doesn't appear automatically after call "reloadInputViews"

Tags: inputaccessoryview

First I subclass UIView named MyTextEditorView for overwrite it's inputAccessoryView as readwrite property.

@property (retain, readwrite) UIView *inputAccessoryView;

And I initial UIInputView as display view,then add one UIView as subview;

```
UIInputVIew *myInputAccessoryView = [[UIInputView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,44)];

[myInputAccessoryView addSubview:myDisplayView];

[self setInputAccessoryView:myInputAccessoryView];

[self reloadInputViews];
```

And I have overriden canBecomeFirstResponder for return YES；

```
- （BOOL）canBecomeFirstResponder
{
     return YES;
}
```

When I first initial MyTextEditorView in my viewController1 and make it become first responder,then inputAccessoryView automatically appear.But when I push another viewController2 from this viewController1 and back to viewController1 ,inputAccessoryView will not automatically appear after make it become first responder.

However,when I add some code as following:

```
    UIInputVIew *myInputAccessoryView = [[UIInputView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,44)];

[myInputAccessoryView addSubview:myDisplayView];

[self setInputAccessoryView:myInputAccessoryView];

[self resignFirstResponder];

[self reloadInputViews];

[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

After then, this inputAccessoryView can automatically appear in any case.But this confused me and anyone can help me raise why the inputAccessoryView can't appear automatically?Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I have got what confused me. This inputAccessoryView appears automatically first, but doesn't work normally after I show UIActionSheet in this viewController's view。My test platform is iOS 8.3! Maybe this is reason of what confused me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test this question on both iOS7 and iOS8. And I find it's an iOS8 bug.After I replace UIActionSheet with UIAlertController on iOS8 platform, this works well.
I guess that UIActionSheet as subclass of UIView is different from UIAlertController as subclass of UIViewController which maybe conflicts with my editor